# Can someone help me recall when Product Rule is used in this way? I vaguely remember it being used this way when learning about ODEs.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Long post, you can read just the first and the second to last paragraph and you should be able to grasp what I'm talking about that way.

I spent a day trying to figure out how a derivation was completed, and the form of the equation reminded me of something that I saw when I was learning about solving ODEs and utilizing the Product Rule of differentiation. If I remember correctly, it was to help with changing the equation into some desired solvable form of an ODE, I just can't remember exactly when this approach was most common or what type of ODEs using the product rule in this way was most common. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Getting into the problem, it's based in physics and engineering (meteorology specifically), but solving the problem only requires knowledge in calculus and mathematics, so do not let this discourage anyone reading from thinking they can help. I'm only going over the general idea behind the process that involved the product rule, not actually going into the process of deriving itself.

Here is the problem in its entirety:

**given:**

$A.\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{z}} = -g\rho$

$B.g \partial{z} =\phi$

$C. p = p(\rho(z))$

$D. Montgomery Streamfunction, M = \frac{p}{\rho} + \phi$

**Show that:**

Equation 1.$\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{\rho}} = -\frac{\partial{\rho \phi}}{\partial{\rho}} \phi + \phi$

Equation 2.$\frac{\partial{\rho M}}{\partial{\rho}} = \phi$

**We will only be focusing on Equation 1**

Here is where the idea of in some way using the Product Rule came into play. Looking at the Right Hand Side (RHS) of Equation 1, you probably notice that this looks like the result of some manipulation of the Product Rule. If not, then it might help if we let $\rho = A$ and $\phi = B$ and derivatives are taken with respect to $\rho$ then we can sub into the following general form for the Product Rule:

$(AB)' = A'B + AB' \rightarrow AB' = (AB)' - A'B$

then subbing in for A and B with their actual variables, we get:

$\rightarrow \frac{\partial{\rho \phi}}{\partial{\rho}} - \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{\rho}}\phi$

and we know $\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{\rho}}$ cancels out to just 1. Recognizing this resemblance with the Product Rule was **crucial** in the final step for obtaining the RHS of Equation 1 which is why I was dead in the water for a day until I remembered the resemblance.

**The negative sign comes in** when we actually go through the process of deriving it all out, so don't worry about that. I just wanted to show the general idea for illustrative purposes.

I know for a fact that I've seen this process before where you have $A'B$ and you expand it into $(AB)' - AB'$ or simplifying $(AB)' - AB'$ into $A'B$ and the same for different arrangements of As, Bs, and primes; I just cannot remember exactly where this was useful aside from this one instance. I feel like if I can find where exactly I dealt with this, then I can be more intuitive with knowing when to do so and not get stuck for a full day.

If anyone would like to see the full derivation for 1 and 2 out of curiosity, I have no problem responding with the full derivations.

Comment: Please don't put random words in code blocks. It's incredibly inconvenient for anyone using a screen reader. Also, they don't seem to actually serve any role in your question.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Would you like me to re-post the question?

Comment: I have edited your question; just keep this in mind in general.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Okay, Thank you! I'll avoid doing that from now on.